# createIconSet is not a function running application on using react-native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Hi I have a project which is created in react native by my friend and i am trying to run that same project on my system it is building project successfully but gives the error attached is the screenshot of same:

[image]

Tried finding solution for the above issue, but not getting any solution.

I tried to uninstall react-native-vector-icons using following command:

```
npm uninstall react-native-vector-icons
```

Also installing it again using the following command:

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons --save
```

But still getting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `rnpm link` after `npm install react-native-vector-icons --save` for automatic installation (easiest way), but you have two more options:

manually:

> Copy the contents in the Fonts folder to
>   android/app/src/main/assets/fonts (note lowercase font folder).
>   Integrating library for getImageSource and ToolbarAndroid support
>
> These steps are optional and only needed if you want to use the
>   Icon.getImageSource function or using custom icons in the
>   Icon.ToolbarAndroid component.
>
> Edit android/settings.gradle to look like this (without the +):
>
> rootProject.name = 'MyApp'
>
> include ':app'
>
> - include ':react-native-vector-icons'
> - project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,
>     '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android') Edit
>     android/app/build.gradle (note: app folder) to look like this:
>
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {   ... }
>
> dependencies {   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>   compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"   compile
>   "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
>   + compile project(':react-native-vector-icons') } Edit your MainActivity.java (deep in android/app/src/main/java/...) to look like
>   this (note two places to edit):
>
> package com.myapp;
>
> - import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
>
> ....
>
> @Override   protected List getPackages() {
>       return Arrays.asList(
>         new MainReactPackage()
>   +   , new VectorIconsPackage()
>       );   }
>
> }

or with gradle:

> Edit android/app/build.gradle and add the following:
>
> apply from:
>   "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle" To
>   customize the files being copied, add the following instead:
>
> project.ext.vectoricons = [
>       iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'EvilIcons.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy ]
>
> apply from:
>   "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

For more info, check on official site: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons